# Retain order when returning dict in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have following function in my flask application, which returns a dictionary to my page.

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search():

    type = request.form['type']
    search = request.form[type]

    results_dict = results.change_filters(type, search)
    print(results_dict)

    return results_dict
```

When i print the dictionary, it is in the correct order, but when returning it to my page, it suddenly loses the order.
My question is, how would you have the dictionary retain its order when returned? If not possible, what alternatives would you recommend?

Comment: check out [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: Are you using CPython 3.6+? Before this version, the order of dictionary elements was undefined.

Comment: @wpercy tried it, but it doesn't seem to affect the order.

Comment: @Seb yup, i am using Python 3.7.1

Comment: *"when returning it to my page"* - do you mean when the page receives it, e.g. as a JSON object? In that case, the problem is that objects in Javascript don't maintain the order of their keys. If the order is important, consider returning it as a list of pairs instead of a dictionary, e.g. `[['type', 'foo'], ['search', 'bar']]` so that the page can iterate through the list in the correct order.

Comment: @kaya3 I am new to this, but im fairly certain it returns as a JSON-object. Would i need to convert my dict to tuples or something? Or is there a way to retain the order of the JSON object?

Comment: in that case I think I agree with kaya, this is probably an issue on the client. if you check the response coming back from your api (in the network tab of chrome for example) are the keys correctly ordered?

Comment: alternatively, if "key-order" is so important, create a new key called "key-order" and put the order of the keys in an array as the value of the key-pair, for eg: `"key-order":["key1", "key2", "key3", "lastKey"]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same problem, it's actually a very simple solution

when configuring your flask app simply set this config value:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["JSON_SORT_KEYS"] = False
```

This should retain the order your dictionary all the way to your page.

Happy Coding

Comment: Dang man. I'm sitting here reading through all these posts why dict ordering changes, and it was Flask doing this the whole time.